# Next.js API Route mysteriously modifying JSON payload

Tags: json, next.js, postman, mime-types, double-quotes

For some reason, when I send JSON formatted data through Postman as raw text, I have no issues. When I send the exact same data through Postman as raw JSON (the difference should only be that the `content-type` header is `application/json` instead of `application/text`), I end up with my double quotes stripped and my strings switched to single quotes.

Original payload example (Postman **sends** this):

```
{ "id": "blahblahbloo", "time": "hammer" }
```

Unintended transformation (NextJS **receives** this):

```
{ id: 'blahblahbloo', time: 'hammer' }
```

To be clear, I get the exact same thing (which is what I expect) when I send as **raw text** via Postman:

```
// Postman sends this and NextJs receives this when set to raw text    
{ "id": "blahblahbloo", "time": "hammer" }
```

I'm not explicitly doing anything to read the `content-type` and transform the data. My endpoints with this issue is a NextJS Dynamic Route: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next.js API routes have a built-in `bodyParser` middleware that will parse the incoming request's body based on its `Content-Type` header.

From the [API Middlewares](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares) documentation (emphasis is mine):

> API routes provide built in middlewares which parse the incoming
> request (`req`). Those middlewares are:
>
> - `req.cookies` - An object containing the cookies sent by the request. Defaults to `{}`
> - `req.query` - An object containing the query string. Defaults to `{}`
> - **`req.body` - An object containing the body parsed by `content-type`, or `null` if no body was sent**

Sending the payload as `application/json` will have the API route convert the `req.body` to a JavaScript object, hence striping the double-quotes.

---

While the `bodyParser` middleware is automatically enabled by default, you can disable it if you want to consume the body yourself.

```js
// In the API route
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false
    }
}
```