# Sending POST request to a Next.js API route sending a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, http-status-code-500

Here is the code for createComment.ts file which is a Next.js api route

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client"


const config = {
  dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATSET,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  useCdn: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  token: process.env.SANITY_API_TOKEN
}

const client  = sanityClient(config);


export default async function createComment(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {

  const {_id, name, email, comment} = req.body

  try {

    await client.create({
      _type: 'comment',
      post: {
        _type: "reference",
        _ref: _id
      },
      name,
      email,
      comment
    })
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({message: "Couldn't submit comment", error})
  }


  console.log("Comment submitted")
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Comment Submitted Successfully' })
}
```

And here is my frontend code which is being used to send a POST request to the api route via Fetch API

```
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = (data) => {
    fetch("/api/createComment", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

I am getting this error even after clearing my cache and restarting the server several times, but no luck.

Comment: can you please post the code instead of screenshots?

Comment: after a second look at your `createComment` endpoint, I see that you're parsing the `req.body` which you shouldn't because Next.js do that by default, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70908053/18457414)

Comment: Tried removing the JSON.parse method but still facing the same issue

Comment: weird, since you already use `catch (error)` do you see any error in `createComment` request response from the Network tab?

Comment: Yes I do see an error, which returns the normal error object called in the catch block

Comment: Can you show us the error you're getting on the server? It should be logged on the terminal where you started the dev server.

Comment: @juliomalves unfortunately thats the main issue, no error is being logged in the server which can help me identify the issue, the only error I see is the 500 Internal Server error and thats also from the console tab in the chrome dev tools.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the API version in the `config` object passed to the `sanityClient`?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error comes from `sanityClient`. Try to make some checks for the .env variables or the token itself that comes from `sanity` are not valid ... who knows?